# CI4 - Adding enctype="multipart/form-data" stopped my validation message from showing up

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

This is the code for my html [create.php]
(please ignore the 'sampul' input in there since it was added after the enctype="multipart/form-data")

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <h2 class="my-3">Form Tambah Data Komik</h2>
            <!-- my itu margin sumbu y (vertikal) -->
            <?php if (session()->getFlashdata('_ci_validation_errors')) : ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach (session()->getFlashdata('_ci_validation_errors') as $error) : ?>
                            <li><?= $error ?></li>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
            <form action="/komik/save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?= csrf_field(); ?>
                <!-- csrf menjaga supaya form cuma bisa diinput lewat halaman ini saja -->
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <label for="judul" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Judul</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control <?= $validation->hasError('judul') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="judul" name="judul" autofocus value="<?= old('judul'); ?>">
                        <!-- autofocus bikin ketika masuk ke page langsung aktif seperti habis di klik -->
                        <div id="validationServer03Feedback" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <?= $validation->getError('judul'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <label for="penulis" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Penulis</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control <?= $validation->hasError('penulis') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="penulis" name="penulis" value="<?= old('penulis'); ?>">
                        <div id="validationServer03Feedback" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <?= $validation->getError('penulis'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <label for="penerbit" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Penerbit</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="penerbit" name="penerbit" value="<?= old('penerbit'); ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <label for="sampul" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Sampul</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <input class="form-control <?= $validation->hasError('sampul') ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" type="file" id="sampul" name="sampul">
                            <div id="validationServer03Feedback" class="invalid-feedback">
                                <?= $validation->getError('sampul'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Tambah Data</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It was working well before, properly showing the error message and showing the 'is-invalid' inside the class in the input, but after adding the enctype="multipart/form-data" inside the form, all of the validation put inside the html just stopped working (including the old used to call back the value if the validation failed).

this is the controller used for this one
The function to get in the create.php

```
public function create()
    {
        // session();
        //session tidak perlu dipanggil karena kita sudah pasang manual session() dalam BaseController.php
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Form Tambah Data Komik',
            // 'validation' => \Config\Services::validation()
            'validation' => session()->getFlashdata('validation') ?? \Config\Services::validation()
        ];

        return view('komik/create', $data);
    }
```

This one is the function to save the form data (validate and return to create.php if it fails the validation)

```
public function save()
    {
        //validasi input
        if (!$this->validate([
            'judul' => [
                'rules' => 'required|is_unique[komik.judul]',
                'errors' => [
                    'required' => '{field} komik harus diisi.',
                    'is_unique' => '{field} komik sudah terdaftar'
                ]
            ],
            'penulis' => [
                'rules' => 'required',
                'errors' => [
                    'required' => '{field} komik harus diisi.'
                ]
            ],
            'sampul' => [
                'rules' => 'uploaded[sampul]|max_size[sampul,1024]|is_image[sampul]|mime_in[sampul,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png]',
                'errors' => [
                    'uploaded' => 'Pilih gambar sampul terlebih dahulu',
                    'max_size' => 'Ukuran gambar terlalu besar',
                    'is_image' => 'Yang anda pilih bukan gambar',
                    'mime_in' => 'Yang anda pilih bukan gambar',
                ]
            ]
        ])) {
            //kalo gagal validasi dia jalankan line ini
            session()->setFlashdata('validation', \Config\Services::validation()); //dari comment YT, bisa jalan
            return redirect()->to('/komik/create')->withInput();
        }

        $slug = url_title($this->request->getVar('judul'), '-', true);
        $this->komikModel->save([
            'judul' => $this->request->getVar('judul'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'penulis' => $this->request->getVar('penulis'),
            'penerbit' => $this->request->getVar('penerbit'),
            'sampul' => $this->request->getVar('sampul')
        ]);

        session()->setFlashdata('pesan', 'Data berhasil ditambahkan.');

        return redirect()->to('/komik');
    }
```

The validation system inside the controller worked just fine, but all error message, the 'is-invalid', and the old stopped showing.

I just don't understand why the error message stopped showing inside the html at all. How does enctype="multipart/form-data" affect this code at all? And can anyone gives me a solution to fix this?